# Flutter - google_sign_in uses allways previously signed in account

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication

I'm trying to sign in and out using firebase google authentication.

When I hit "Sign in with Google", I can choose the account, but the previous user gets loaded.

This is my code of the class that I'm using to log in and log out:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart";
import "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart";
import "package:goouser/global.dart" as global;
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class GoogleLog extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  Future googleLogin() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) return;
      _user = googleUser;

      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    notifyListeners();


  }

  Future logOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
  }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include:

```
GoogleSignIn().disconnect()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).